# JavaScript content assist not working for JSP file in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jsp, eclipse-kepler

I am using Eclipse Kepler to develop App Engine application.The autocomplete feature is not working for JSP files and am not sure if I am missing any Property settings.
[image]

Would be glad if someone can let me know what needs to be done to enable auto-complete feature?

PS : FYI, I have the WTP tool already installed

[image]

Comment: Autocomplete for what language?

Comment: hi @nitind, The snapshot I have given is the Javascript code inside JSP file. I am expecting the autocomplete to work for the Javascript code. Let me know if you need any other detail

Answer (score 0):

You have to be working with a file in a JavaScript Source Folder. To do that, you can create a JavaScript project or enable an existing project from its Configure context menu (right-click->Configure->something JavaScript). Once that's done, if it wasn't opened automatically, bring up the project's JavaScript Include Path property page and create or mark an existing folder as a Source Folder. That should enable it for both JS files and web pages.

Comment: Hi @nitind, thanks. Am sorry if I am naive..as I am new to Web technologies. My application is basically a Webapplication(app-engine) project. Is converting the application to JavaScript(I could see an option configure->Covert to Javascript project) from an appengine project will not have any impact?. Also, would be glad if you can let me know more about the 'Include path property' page. PS : Please note the javascript code is inside .jsp(Java server pages) file

Comment: It adds files to the project's .settings folder, and makes a change to the project's .project file (these might be hidden by default). It will make content assist available, but content assist for a dynamic language like JavaScript can easily be imperfect, and it can impact overall performance. You can find the 'JavaScript'->'Include Path' page by right-clicking on the project and choosing 'Properties' and expanding the 'JavaScript' category.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried closing the project and opening it again. That would clear the cache and get things running.

right click project > close project
right click closed project > open project